# Problems with connection in oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Every time I restart or shutdown my computer, I need to make this  command to connect to my database.

1. `lsnrctl start` in shell (i'm working with ubuntu)
2. `startup` in SQL commands(because it says that I'm connected as idle instance)
3. then I connect again to sql  to grant System and Object Privileges in Oracle Database, (it doesn't work and I still don't have the privileges except in shell)

So my problem is that  I don't understand why I have to always tap these commands after restarting my computer.

Second is that I can't create tables or accesses to tables in sqldeveloper or in eclipse because I don't have all the privileges. Please, is there someone here who has any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Linux.

However, on MS Windows, if you set listener and database services to start up automatically (when computer starts up), then database should be available to you in a matter of minutes. If you can't do that on Ubuntu, then yes - you have to start the database manually.

As of your second question: user you'd like to use to create tables, procedures etc. should be granted certain privileges. They are granted by the same privileged user that created it, such as SYS. So: you'd connect as SYS and then run the some grants (presuming that your user name is "beline"); for example:

```
grant create session       to beline;
grant create table         to beline;
grant create procedure     to beline;
grant create sequence      to beline;
grant create view          to beline;
```

There are other privileges as well; grant them when necessary.

Once granted, they'll last "forever" (until you explicitly revoke them), which means that they will still be available to you after database restarts.
    grant create trigger       to beline;

Comment: First, you need to know that oracle was never intended, designed, tested, or certified on Ubuntu, which is an entirely different branch of the Linux family.  There are hacks to get it installed, but they are just that - hacks.  Second database privs have nothing to do with the shell ("it doesn't work and i still don't have the privileges except in shell) .  If you GRANT  a privilege, that is entirely within the database and will remain until specifically REVOKed.  Third, "it dosn't work" conveys zero actionable information.

Comment: @EdStevens - I think this is the second time in the last day or so I've seen you comment on an answer when I think you meant to comment on the question.  :-) Are you using the SO mobile app?

Comment: No mobile app.  Just getting careless, I guess.  Thanks for pointing it up.  The very fact that you pointed it up will help reinforce it for me.  Thangs.

Comment: it was an express edition, so no need hacks to get it installed?